# Is the following schema model declared correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to Mongoose and nodejs. Trying to make a simple project. I'm trying to create a schema which has the following fields. I'm trying to stringify it at the frontend and JSON.parse it at the backend.
I'm getting an error "cast to array failed for value".

```js
var studentSchema = new Schema({
     
    profileNum              : {type:String},
    eMail                   : {type:String},
 preferredLocation     : [],
 gender                  : {type:String,default:''},
 education               : [{institute:String,batch:Number,course:String}],
 profession              : [],
 designation             : {type:String,default:''},
 organization            : {type:String,default:''} 

});
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: @DevDig At the frontend in angular, I'm performing this `$scope.education = JSON.stringify($scope.education);` and then sending the data. Doing this at the backend `var educationDetail = req.body.education;
            educationDetail = JSON.parse(educationDetail);
            result.education = educationDetail;`

Comment: What does `$scope.education` look like?

Comment: @str `["something",123546,"gh"]`  The error in specific is this `err ValidationError: CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "[ 'something', 123546, 'gh' ]" at path "education"
`

Comment: what are u sending in  the req.body  in backend  ?

Comment: @Sam Look at my first comment. I'm taking `req.body.education` at the backend. Also, in the mongoose schema model, is that the correct syntax for education?

Comment: according to your schema u have to send array of object in education [ {'something', 123546, 'gh'} ]

Comment: @Sam Doesn't the `JSON.parse` command convert it into an object?

Answer (score 0):

For your `education` path, you might either use `[Schema.Types.Mixed]` or create a new Schema for education subdocuments and use `[EducationSchema]` if you need types or additional middleware/validations.